# Routing to a complete new template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

I've learning this new tool since some days ago and know I'm beggining to have my own doubts.

I have an index.html, which holds almost all my app like so:

```
<html>
<head>
.
.
.
<body>
<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
.
<!-- Loads all the scripts and other stuff-->
</body>
```

Ok, in the website I'm building, I have some sections that share the header, that's why I include it. Nonetheless, there is another section where is completely different from the others, hence, I don't need to include the header.
Now, the question is: How can I route to this completely new section ? Because the index loads the other views in the below the header. All I can think about right now is creating another index.html-like page, loading all the scripts and everything again. I think there should be a more elegant solution in Angular.
I'm using angular-ui-router for the routing.
Can you please give me a hand? Thanks

Comment: why not put the header inside the template for the routes that need it?

Comment: Theres a ton of different solutions to do this. For one, you can just hide the header on certain routes. Use your imagination!

Comment: Thank you both, I'm going for Claiese's answer for know.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested states, put this in your app's state configuration.

```
$stateProvider.
  $state('stateWithHeader', {
    template: '<header></header><div ui-view></div>',
    controller: 'HeaderStateController'
  }
  .$state('stateWithHeader.subState', {
    template: '<div>Content!</div>',
    controller: 'HaderSubStateController'
  }
  .$state('stateWithoutHeader', {
    template: '<div>Yeah, no header!</div>',
    controller: 'HeaderStateController'
  };
```

Make sure to read the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views), they're super informative and clear on most subjects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll keep this in mind as I get along and fight with Angular! :)

Answer (score 0):

What @Claies said above will absolutely work. Here's an example from my own site at http://PaperQuik.com.

I have multiple routes which correspond to different templates. Each one just does the following to get the same menu header at the top of the page:

```
<div ng-include="'views/menu.html'"></div>
```

If I needed a different top I could use a different include. You can see the source to my various templates here: https://github.com/JohnMunsch/PaperQuik/tree/master/app/views

Note: My example is just using the old ngRouter (not the new one which is expected for AngularJS 1.4) and thus it is way less sophisticated than what you can do with either the new ngRouter or the AngularUI Router you're using. Still, you can see how easy it is even with that super simple router.